# Bind to another bind (scheme explanation added)

Tags: redirect, bind

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqn3h.png]

I have example.com declared on my web server, which is a production server in an OVH datacenter.

I need to forward redmine.exemple.com to our Mac mini server (based in our office, behind our ISP box which forwards everything to the Apple computer).

We have used VMWare fusion and a specific VM: bitnami redmine stack.

How can I configure the second bind on our Mac mini server to forward a specific domain to a specific VM?

Currently everything coming from port 80 is redirected to the Mac mini server and not to a specific VM, is there a special configuration for that?

I have installed bind on the Mac mini but it's not being used by inbound traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using bind "views", each view will be given to a different machine depending on some parameters defined by an ACL, so you can in effect do things like

- All machines in network AA.BB.CC.DD can see this domain as XXX but the machine AA.BB.CC.EE will see YYY

This of course means maintaining two different files for your zone, so if you just want one and only one entry the best you can do is to define that entry as a subdomain (just point NS and create a separate file, then point @ A to the IP in question) so you can keep those two files separate with what you want.

Another option if you don't want to do that is just declare a zone which is mastered in the macmini with the entry you want, define that as a full domain and again put @ A to the IP of the VM, then the mac mini will think that he's the master of that zone and since it's a subdomain any queries to your main domain will still get good answers from outside.